# 'Reading Assembly' I can't understand how this function works

Tags: c, assembly

[enter image description here][1]

```
   0x000000000000117c <+0>:     test   %edi,%edi
   0x000000000000117e <+2>:     jne    0x1186 <F2+10>
   0x0000000000001180 <+4>:     mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000001185 <+9>:     retq
   0x0000000000001186 <+10>:    push   %rbx
   0x0000000000001187 <+11>:    mov    %edi,%ebx
   0x0000000000001189 <+13>:    lea    -0x1(%rdi),%edi
   0x000000000000118c <+16>:    callq  0x117c <F2>
   0x0000000000001191 <+21>:    imul   %ebx,%eax
   0x0000000000001194 <+24>:    pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000001195 <+25>:    retq
```

Question 1

In <+13>, if you give -0x1 (%rdi) to %edi through lea, instead of subtracting 1 from the %edi value, the address of %rdi minus 1 is entered in %edi. Why is this necessary and what does it mean?

Question 2.

It doesn't make sense to have two retqs in one function.
After test %edi,%edi, jump to jne and then use a recursive function. Then I don't know why there are two retqs in <+9> and <+25>. Shouldn't there be only one?

Question 3.
It's hard to understand what a function basically does, as I'm just learning assembly. What kind of operation does the function do?

Comment: Can you see a `jne` which branches past the first `retq`? The first `retq` is how the recursion ends. Instead of the first `retq` they could have jumped to the second `retq`. But they didn't.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code.

Comment: I edit the  picture to code  :)

Comment: `lea edi, [rdi - 1]` results in `edi` being decremented. Using a 64-bit effective address with `rdi` is an optimisation so as not to require an `asize` / `a32` prefix (machine code byte 67h). The low 32 bits of `rdi - 1` exactly match those of `edi - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1

It *does* compute `parameter - 1`, right? The compiler obviously prefers LEA, possibly because it is short, possibly because of some other reason.

Question 2

I bet there are also two `return` statements in the C code. The first being

```
if (parameter == 0)
   return 1;
```

so that is the first part. The second part returns a different value, so is done separately.

Jumping to a return saves you nothing, as the code for a jump is larger than the return.

Question 3

Yes, it is hard to decode assembly. Seems like it computes

```
x * F2(x-1)
```

whatever that means.

Comment: so it seems like function for factorial...thanks!

Comment: `lea -1(%rdi), %edi` is 3 bytes, same as `sub $1, %edi`.  `dec %edi` would be only 2 bytes (not 1 since this is x86-64).  A few compilers seem to prefer LEA, at least with some tuning options, but on most CPUs not better.  On ancient in-order Atom, LEA needs its input earlier, but can produce a result earlier, so there can be advantages in having the result ready sooner for the next instruction.  Otherwise it just runs on an execution unit same as other math.  The normal reason to use LEA is to copy-and-add, like `lea -1(%rdi), %ebx` if that had been useful.

Comment: And yup, this looks like a recursive factorial, which just shows how crazily inefficient recursion is when it's not needed.  An iterative loop using `imul` the same way would need less code, and more importantly the number of instructions *executed* would be lower, and not involve a lot of call/ret.